# Update id value of a model in loopback

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, loopbackjs

Updating the **id** of a model does not seem possible (**DB: mysql**).

I tried the following PUT request:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/api/company/google
{
    "name":"alphabet"
}
```

Response:

```
"error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 400,
    "message": "id property (undefined) cannot be updated from undefined to undefined",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "stack":"....etc"
}
```

If not possible through the built-in REST API how can I do that ? Can I use the node API server-side to update the **id** of a model?

Been trying this for two days, No luck.
Thanks.

Comment: does your `company` model has property `idInjection` set to `false`? Also have you defined `id` attribute for you model?

Comment: first of all sorry for the late reply, I found that idInjection was set to false and second the method was't POST method, It's PUT request,
Even i changed the idInjection to true. Still the same error shows up,

Comment: name is currently set as ID here,

Comment: Hey could you add the error stack to your question ? I am trying to improve the error message in loopback and it would help me locating where it's thrown. Thanks!

Comment: That error message contained a formatting bug in loopback-datasource-juggler that is [fixed](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/1196) now. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to update the ID of model's instance, because that would break all relations to this instance.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182045/change-primary-key-id-of-a-row-in-a-table-and-shift-the-others-downwards) that indicates the key of a model should never be changed for MySQL tables

That being said, I don't think you actually need to update your ID in your situation. Keep `idInjection` to false, and do not set `id` for property `name`.

Then you can execute this one request

`POST  http://localhost:3000/api/company/update?where[name]=Google`

```
{
   "name": "alphabet"
}
```

Is this helpful ?