# Error #1062 Mysql Duplicate Entry for the key primary

Tags: mysql

I have big MySql table 'docs' (above 3 000 000 rows).
This table have column `id` --- primary key unsigned and `did` ----- unsigned.
Sometimes some rows deleted. But I need that autoincrement go 1234 and not 1479.
I perform sql request:

```
update docs set id=@num:=@num+1 where 0 in(select @num:=0)
```

and receive error #1062.

2 questions:
1. Why I have duplicate entry for the key primary?
2. How I can delete them?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are no duplicate entries in your table. You misread the error. The error (#1062) you get says that your update operation *would* result in a duplicate key.

Comment: So how I can update primary keys in the table?

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182045/change-primary-key-id-of-a-row-in-a-table-and-shift-the-others-downwards

Comment: It's no good idea to do this. Primary keys should be used to identify data rows and nothing else. If you need to give consecutive numbers to your rows consider adding another column which is no key but just additional info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change primary key (id) of a row in a table and shift the others downwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182045/change-primary-key-id-of-a-row-in-a-table-and-shift-the-others-downwards)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is more easy (remove and add primary):
ALTER TABLE `docs`DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE `docs` ADD `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);