# How to id column value from table view from an other class to replace the count value?

Tags: javafx, fxml

public class Customer {

```
private static int count = 1;

public Customer(String x, String y) {
    super();
    this.x = new Simple-String-Property(x);
    this.y = new Simple-String-Property(y);
    this.id = new Simple-Integer-Property(count);
    count++;
    
}
```

I have an abstract table which populate data from database after the application start. So i want my id column auto increment after retrieving data. So i use the variable count for static and it work fine. However, when i submit the abstract data to table, the id column back to 1 even though the data on the table show up different number depending from populated database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are those dashes in the class name?

Second, if the ID is the primary key it might actually be a feature that you can't change it.

[Change primary key (id) of a row in a table and shift the others downwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182045/change-primary-key-id-of-a-row-in-a-table-and-shift-the-others-downwards)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes those are classes because stackoverflow gave me an error when posting. The id in my sql database is primary auto increment. But it not primary in my abstract table.